# How to adjust geom_point dodge width to match geom_boxplot width when varwidth = TRUE?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to match ggplot geom_point position dodging width to a geom_boxplot width that is adjusted to the number of data points using the varwidth = TRUE option in geom_boxplot? This would require different dodging widths for each group. Demonstration:

```
# Question about dodging widths 
library(tidyverse)
count(iris, Species)

# Reduce the virginica data to have many less rows by filtering by Petal.Length
df <- iris %>% filter(!(Species == "virginica" & Petal.Length > 5))
count(df, Species)

# Demonstration plot, with this width, setosa and versicolor dodging doesn't use entire box width
ggplot(df, aes(x=Species, y=Petal.Width)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA, varwidth = TRUE) + 
  geom_point(position = position_dodge2(width = 0.5), alpha = 0.2)

# Thought something like this might work to manually force widths, but no such luck ...
ggplot(df, aes(x=Species, y=Petal.Width)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA, varwidth = TRUE) + 
  geom_point(position = position_dodge2(width = c(0.75, 0.75, 0.25)), alpha = 0.2)
```

[Demonstration plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZMZZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you only specify 3 values, but you have many more points. One way to do this is to specify every point:

```
df$wids<-rep(0,length(row.names(df)))
df$wids[which(df$Species=="virginica")]=0.25
df$wids[which(df$Species=="versicolor")]=.75
df$wids[which(df$Species=="setosa")]=.75


# Thought something like this might work to manually force widths, but no such luck ...
ggplot(df, aes(x=Species, y=Petal.Width)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA, varwidth = TRUE) + 
  geom_point(position = position_dodge2(width = df$wids), alpha = 0.2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this does accomplish the manual integration. Still wondering if there is a way to automate the widths to whatever the varwidth parameter in the boxplot determines.

Comment: Yes, I know it is a bit of a messy hack.. it seems like I am always creating solutions like this, but if there is a canned way to do this already within `ggplot` that would be great.